# Karma inside sublime text

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2, karma-runner

Egghead.io has an awesome video where the karma tests are running as he types or saves the page. Does Sublime text have a similar plugin?

I have been looking into build systems, but for some reason this build doesn't work in my ST3:

```
{
  "path": "/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH",
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
  "cmd": ["karma", "start"]
}
```

Comment: You can also enable a watcher on the karma config using the `autoWatch` option: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: @MarcoCI Yep, love that option. Can it be outputted in the console in sublime text for example?